# Given $x >0$ and $n$ is contained in $N$, show that there exists a unique positive real number $r$ such that $x = r^n$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Also, $r$ is usually denoted by $x^{\frac{1}{n}}$

I'm having a lot of issues with this problem. It is a challenge problem and I feel as though I've done all of it completely wrong. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Show that the set $\{t\in\Bbb R_{\geq0}:t^n\leq x\}$ is non-empty and bounded above. What do we know about such subsets of the real line?

Or, you can use/prove the fact that $t\mapsto t^n$ is a strictly increasing continuous function on the nonnegative reals, and the conclusion follows fairly readily.